# doOnNext() does not exist in io.reactivex.Single

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm migrating an app from RxJava 1 to 2. I have a code like this:

**RxJava 1**

```
public Completable update() {
    return client.fetchNotes()
        .map(toNote())
        .toList()
        .doOnNext(save())
        .toCompletable();
}
```

In code above, `toList()` returns a `Observable<List<Note>>`.

Now, I'm trying to transform that code to RxJava 2:

**RxJava 2**

```
public Completable update() {
    return client.fetchNotes()
        .map(toNote())
        .toList()
        .doOnNext(save()) // <-- compilation error here
        .ignoreElements();
}
```

In RxJava 2, `toList()` returns a `Single<List<Note>>`, so I can't chain `doOnNext(save())` to it, because `doOnNext()` does not exist in `Single<T>.class`.

How can I obtain the same behavior in both cases? Basically, in `save()` method, I'm storing the `Note`s in a database and it has to be from a `List<Note>`; `Database` interface I'm using does not allow storing one by one. That's why I need to use `toList()`:

```
interface Database {
    void store(List<Note> notes);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried typing dot `.` followed by `d` `o` `O` `n` after `toList()` to see what options your IDE brings up?

Comment: When I tried with `Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta",
                "Epsilon")
                 .toList()
                 .doON....
                 .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Received: " + s));` got doOnDispose , doOnError, doOnEvent, doOnSubscrib, doOnSuccess for code completions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a `Single` only emits one item, it doesn't have a concept of "next" or a `doOnNext()` operator. Instead use `doOnSuccess()`.

Comment: (Or of course use a SingleSubscriber's `onSuccess()` method to process the List. Should eliminate the need for `.ignoreElements()`.)